# Ordering a material science dataset (properties names, properties scalars, formulas)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm dealing with a materials science dataset and I'm in the following situation,

I have data organized like this:

```
Chemical_ Formula     Property_name            Property_Scalar

    He                Electrical conduc.          1
    NO_2              Resistance                  50
    CuO3              Hardness
    ...               ...                        ...
    CuO3              Fluorescence                300
    He                Toxicity                    39
    NO2               Hardness                    80
    ...               ...                         ...
```

As you can understand it is really messy because the same chemical formula appears more than once through the entire dataset, but referred to a different property that is considered. My question is, how can I easily maybe split the dataset in smaller ones, fitting every formula with its descriptors in ORDER? I really need help on this... thank you.  ( I used fiction names and values, just to explain my problem.)

I'm on Jupyter Notebook and I'm using Pandas.

I'm editing my question trying to be more clear:

My goal would be to plot some histograms of (for example) n°materials vs conductivity at different temperatures (100K, 200K, 300K). So I need to have both conductivity and temperature for each material to be clearly comparable. For example, I guess that a more convenient thing to obtain would be:

```
Chemical formula     Conductivity      Temperature

      He                 5                  10K
      NO_2               7                  59K
      CuO_3              10                 300K
      ...                ...                ...
      He                 14                 100K
      NO_2               5                  70K
      ...                ...                ...
```

Comment: This looks similar to a [tidy format](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=tidy). Your question is not clear: what exactly do you want to obtain? If you just want to group the rows by the first column, you can simply order the dataframe by alphabetical order of the first column.

Comment: thank you @Erwan for your comment. I edited my post writing what I guess it would be a more convenient format to have the data, and also what I want to do with that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It's indeed related to converting between different dataframe "formats". I know how to do this with R but I'm not familiar with Pandas, this kind of manipulation is usually called "reshaping" or "melting" data, see for instance [here](https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/06/reshaping-dataframes-with-pandas-melt-and-wide_to_long/). In your case you'll need two steps: first filter only the rows of the properties you want (conductivity and temperature) and then "melt" in order to obtain a "wide fromat" with a different column for each property.

Comment: but if I do this way.. will the two features (Temperature and conductivity) match for every single chemical formula?

Comment: If the data contains these two features for every formula, yes it will. But if there are formulas in the data which don't have them (missing data), then these formulas won't be included.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your Dataframe is:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Chemical_Formula":["He", "NO_2", "CuO3", "CuO3", "He", "NO2"],
    "Property_name":["Electrical conduc.", "Resistance", "Hardness", "Fluorescence", "Toxicity", "Hardness"],
    "Property_Scalar":[1, 50, 10, 300, 39, 80]
})
```

|  | Chemical_Formula | Property_name | Property_Scalar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | He | Electrical conduc. | 1 |
| 1 | NO_2 | Resistance | 50 |
| 2 | CuO3 | Hardness | 10 |
| 3 | CuO3 | Fluorescence | 300 |
| 4 | He | Toxicity | 39 |
| 5 | NO2 | Hardness | 80 |

You can use pivot to "unmelt" this in a wide format

```py
df3 = df2.pivot(index="Chemical_Formula", columns="Property_name")
```

| Chemical_Formula | ('Property_Scalar', 'Electrical conduc.') | ('Property_Scalar', 'Fluorescence') | ('Property_Scalar', 'Hardness') | ('Property_Scalar', 'Resistance') | ('Property_Scalar', 'Toxicity') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CuO3 | nan | 300 | 10 | nan | nan |
| He | 1 | nan | nan | nan | 39 |
| NO2 | nan | nan | 80 | nan | nan |
| NO_2 | nan | nan | nan | 50 | nan |

From then on you can drop columns you don't need and plot them.

Comment: That's cool but the only problem is that they do not result aligned I mean, I have a bunch of NaNs at this point. For example I have 300 Fluorescence for CuO3 and it' s OK but on Electrical Condct is NaN. This means that somewhere on the large Dataset I'll have another CuO3 underr 'Chemical_Formula' with some scalar value for electrical cond and NaN for Fluorescence. I'm wondering how to end up with a clear aligned-properties dataset :S

Comment: It will only have NaNs when pivot can not find the variable to match in case of another entry.
If there are two rows like you described then they will be put togethr in a single resulting row.

Try running this on your code, or provide data to match this issue, thanks!